# How to create a jar file in a specific location?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powershell, batch-file, jar

I would like to create a .jar file in a specific location with a C# program.
For this, I am using Process.Start(Program, Parameters) from System.Diagnostics.
The Problem is using something like

```
jar cvf Test.jar test.class
```

does not help, because it is searching for the Files in the Runtime Location.
I searched for some other launch parameters and I found -C DIR for "switch to the given path and get the given file". But using it like

```
jar cvf -C C:\somelocation Test.jar test.class
```

just prints the error "test.class cannot be found" and when I am using it like

```
jar cvf -C C:\somelocation Test.jar -C C:\somelocation test.class
```

it produces a runtime Error. Not getting further I tried to start CMD with some Parameters like

```
cmd /d /E:ON /k cd C:\somelocation jar cvf Test.jar test.class
```

, but it did not work. I could start a batch file with something like

```
cd C:\somelocation
jar cvf Test.jar test.class
```

, but it is just bad coding.
It would be awesome if someone would know any working set of parameters or some way to use PowerShell or Batch scripting in Visual Studio with C#.

Thanks for every response.

Greetings Chuck Norris

Comment: You are giving `CMD.exe` two commands to run, so you would have to concatenate them with the ampersand.  I am not a java expert, so I don't know the syntax of that but if you need to run two commands with `CMD.EXE` you would run it like so: `cmd /C "cd /D C:\somefolder & myprogram.exe"`

Comment: Your other option is to set the working directory with the `START` command using the `/D` option. `CMD /C START "Window Title" /D "C:\somefolder" "Myprogram.exe"`

Comment: Are you sure you have the jar parameters in the right order? According to first page I looked at, the jar syntax is `jar c[v0M]f jarfile [-C dir] inputfiles [-Joption]`, which would mean you should be using `jar cvf test.jar -C C:\somelocation test.class`

Comment: If you need `test.jar` to be created in a specific location, can't you pass the full path e.g. `jar cvf c:\somepath\test.jar -C c:\somelocation test.class`

Comment: Thank's very much for the answers!

Comment: @Squashman your first explanation works perfectly thank you very much! :)

Comment: @andyb Thanks for your answers, too but they are not working for me. :)

Comment: That's odd. I did test the parameter sequence that I suggested and it appeared to work.